# Typescript style guide for interfaces

Tags: typescript, angular

this is a question that may not have a single correct answer, as I do realise coding styles are quite varied, especially between different languages, eg camel case function names in javascript vs pascal casing methods in C#. I can quite accept that.

Maybe I am over worrying about this, but I am just starting to look into typescript, really like the looks of it and plan to use it along with Angular2,  and want to establish a good style guide.

What I really don't get is point 2 [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Coding-guidelines), not to use I prefix for interfaces. Until this, I thought that was almost universal. I have a class Car, so a natural name if the interface is just to add an I in front... ICar. As soon as you see the  I prefix you know you have an interface.

I want to follow any suggested practice, but this one I really do not know which why to go.

Does none know why, what I thought was an almost universal convention, is being discouraged here? I know you can use whatever conventions you like, just wondering if there is some reason for this common convention not to be used in Typescript.

Thanks in advance for any opinions/info!

Answer (score 14):

`I` as prefix was big at some time for Java and C# (probably also others) but I don't think this is still considered a good idea but how can one change something that is used by the majority of developers and existing code base.

It's similar to hungarian notation which is universally considered bad practice. Just give it a meaningful name. If you have different kinds of `Car`s than make `Car` the universal interface and `class FancyCar implements Car` is much more natural. Things like prefixes just prevent people from thinking about what they really want to express. See also http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?IntentionRevealingNames

There are also languages like Dart (probably many others I don't know) where there is not such a clear distinction between `interface` and `class`. In Dart you can implement any class. The class' interface just acts as an `interface`.

**update**

I don't say naming is easy. In fact I think it's the most or at least among the most difficult parts of software development. It's just that the general consesus of "the elite" is that prefixes for technical reasons are not the best approach. This doesn't mean there are alternative that have only advantages and no drawbacks. It seems in this case naming like `UserService`, `UserServiceImpl`, `MockUserService` is used instead. This way in most parts of your code the most natural way `UserService` is used and the derivates only in prividers. Otherwise, as mentioned above, consistency is way more important. If some style is more common in the language you use, I suggest to use this in your code as well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The `FancyCar implements Car` etc argument works when you use the interfaces for polymorphic reasons, however often, e.g. say an Angular service, there will be one instance, e.g. `FileSystemService`, `UserService`, and we may implement them all to an interface so we always inject the interface and not the concrete class into the service consumers. This then enables easy mocking of classes to the interface etc. This would mean you need to think of an alternative name for every service's interface, rather than a simple prefix (e.g. `IFileSystemService`, `IUserService`).

Comment: Thanks again for your comments. I suppose we could use suffixes instead of prefixes, but till the same thing in the end isn't it? I suppose we would also use `FileSystemServiceInterface` as well. I've seen quite a few tutorials with the "I" in interfaces (by highly respected authorities in the js word), that's why I initially thought it would follow similar conventions to lclass based languages such as C# (where it is use it all the time), and why surprised when I later saw the style guide, and that it targeted this one convention so specifically. All food for thought.

Comment: I think the intention is, as mentioned in my previous comment, to not use a prefix or suffix on the **interface** because this is (usually) the one used throughout your application, while the `UserServiceImpl` is probably only used for example in a factory that returns a concrete instance (if not a factory then probably still only in very few places in your application compared to the number of occurrences of the interface).

Comment: Yes, so turn it around and "mark" the class as opposed to the interface. Old MS C++ MFC style use to use "C" prefix for the classes (eg CFileSystemService), as well as the dreaded full Hungarian notation (which of course was terrible).  All food for thought . Perhaps the "C" prefix is maybe not so bad, but don't see it used anywhere anymore, and just feels old school. Will keep an eye out for more examples,  as more Angular 2 content becomes available, where there will be many examples of Components/services, and the unit test mocking. Be interesting to see what conventions will be adapted.

Comment: It's worth noting that Microsoft still recommends the "I" prefix in C# as of March 2017: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-classes-structs-and-interfaces

Comment: @TravisWilson More over in retrospect one of .NET architects (Brad Abrams) thinks it would have been better not using I prefix. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brada/2004/02/03/why-do-interface-names-begin-with-i/ TypeScript is COM-legacy-free thereby it has no I-prefix-for-interface rule.

Answer (score 5):

Similar question is asked here [Confused about the Interface and Class coding guidelines for TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876947/confused-about-the-interface-and-class-coding-guidelines-for-typescript/)

My answer on it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41967120/586609

Reasons:

1. The times of the Hungarian notation have passed
2. I-prefix violates encapsulation principle
3. Protection from bad naming
4. Properly chosen names vaccinate you against API Design Myth: Interface as Contract.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason why to do or not do something other than because it is idiomatic. If you want your code to fit in, you follow the rules everyone else follows in the language you are using and don’t think about it (or pick another language).

As far as specifically why not put a prefix, there are three very good reasons:

1. Interfaces are implicitly created when you use the `class` keyword, and are also created when you use the `type` keyword. So, by adding a prefix to your explicitly declared interfaces, now you have *some* interfaces with a prefix (the ones you created yourself with the prefix), plus a ton more interfaces without a prefix. This is confusing and inconsistent.
2. Types (interfaces) and code exist in independent namespaces in the compiler, so you cannot conflict a type name and a variable name. Therefore there is no reason to try to make interface names unique by prefixing them.
3. `I` prefixing is just another form of systems hungarian notation; saying a type is an interface provides *zero* additional information to the human writing the code.

Comment: @C Snover Does it not tell the coder that they are working with  something that will behave polymorphically?

Comment: It's worth noting that Microsoft still recommends the "I" prefix in C# as of March 2017: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-classes-structs-and-interfaces

Comment: TypeScript and C# are not the same language so they do not have the same conventions. This is confusing, I know. ;) [Microsoft’s coding guidelines for TypeScript itself](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Coding-guidelines#names) forbid the I prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Two more reasons

**Modularization** As the code base grows, the code starts to be modularized. The usual design goal with modules is to expose contracts and hides the internals. Contracts are best expressed by interfaces and after a while most if not all exposed artifacts are interfaces and factories. For consumers of these modules it is nicer to work with `Users`s and `Credentials` rather than `IUsers` and `ICredentials`

**Alphabetic order** For instance quick access to  Interfaces and Classes in lists sorted in alphabetic order in a File navigator. When working with Users, it is best to have `User`, `UserService` and `UserImpl` next to each other in the list, rather than having to go though the `I` entries, then the `C` entries then the `Service` entries

Comment: Thanks for that. I have actually now got use to it, and also now realise that Interfaces in TypeScript are also a bit more general than in a language like C#.