# ng build fails with cannot find module error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I wanted to build my angular project automatically on a different CentOS 7 machine.

Following Versions are used:

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.23
Node: 13.14.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 8.2.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package Version

@angular-devkit/architect 0.803.23
@angular-devkit/build-angular 0.803.25
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr 0.803.23
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer 0.803.25
@angular-devkit/build-webpack 0.803.25
@angular-devkit/core 8.3.23
@angular-devkit/schematics 8.3.23
@angular/cdk 8.2.3
@angular/cli 8.3.23
@angular/http 7.2.16
@angular/material 8.2.3
@ngtools/webpack 8.3.25
@schematics/angular 8.3.23
@schematics/update 0.803.23
rxjs 6.5.5
typescript 3.4.5
webpack 4.39.2
```

Also Node version 12 doesn't change anything.

The Build Errors:

```
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 655 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 127 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills-es5} polyfills-es5.js, polyfills-es5.js.map (polyfills-es5) 463 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 43.9 kB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-06-25T10:35:22.517Z - Hash: 82d7bfce3451c02dfe5f - Time: 11782ms

ERROR in app/interfaces/ISharepoint.ts:5:22 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './IQuota'.

5 import {IQuota} from './IQuota';
app/interfaces/ISharepointUser.ts:4:22 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './IQuota'.

4 import {IQuota} from "./IQuota";
app/interfaces/isharepointnetwork.ts:3:22 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../interfaces/IQuota'.

3 import {IQuota} from "../interfaces/IQuota";
app/sharepoints/InitializeSharepointProperties.ts:7:34 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../interfaces/ISharepointNetwork'.

7 import {ISharepointNetwork} from '../interfaces/ISharepointNetwork';
app/sharepoints/sharepoints.component.ts:32:22 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../interfaces/IQuota'.

32 import {IQuota} from '../interfaces/IQuota';
```

How can I fix this issue?

---

My app.modoule.ts

```
export const appRouterProviders = [
    provideRoutes(appRoutes)
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        DashboardComponent,
        ProfilesComponent,
        NetworksComponent,
        ServicesComponent,
        SystemComponent,
        SharepointsComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        AuthenticationComponent,
        ErrorComponent,
        LogsComponent,
        FilterTimezone,
        FileSizePipe,
        MatchHeightDirective,
        NtpComponent,
        P5Component,
        DndDirective,
        ProgressComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        MultiSelectModule,
        ChipsModule,
        MaterializeModule,
        ChartModule,
        CheckboxModule,
        DragDropModule,
        ListboxModule,
        PickListModule,
        FormsModule,
        TooltipModule,
        TreeModule,
        InputMaskModule,
        TableModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        MaterializeModule,
        DialogModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
        MalihuScrollbarModule.forRoot(),
        RouterModule,
        ProgressBarModule,
        MessagesModule,
        TooltipModule,
        PickListModule,
        EditorModule,
        NgMultiSelectDropDownModule.forRoot(),
        LocalStorageModule.forRoot({
            prefix: 'juststore',
            storageType: 'localStorage'
        }),
        UiSwitchModule,
        AngularEditorModule
    ],
    providers: [
        provideRoutes(appRoutes),
        HttpClient,
        ToaauthenticationService,
        LocalStorageService,
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: HTTPAuthHeader,
            multi: true
        }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: What does app.module look like?

Comment: IQuota file and export  exists  ?

Comment: IQuota.ts exits and contains:

export interface IQuota {
    quotaSupport: boolean;
    quotaEnabled: boolean;
    quotaReport: IQuotaLimits;
    quotaUsage: number;
}

Comment: the interesting thing is that the project builds on the other Mac machine without errors

Comment: Do not prefix interface names with "I",  [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31876947/13596406)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I renamed all Interfaces and removed the leading I from the names and now the build process is working as expected.