# Some interfaces (e.g. IUser or IData) use "I" as the beginning of the interface name, why?

Tags: typescript

Does this I refer to the interface or person？Such as:

```js
interface IUser extends Document {
  email: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}
```

Comment: The `I` is for "interface". It's just a naming scheme some people use; you don't have to do it.

Comment: Some reading here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41967120/10691359 explains the situation. As stated by @NicholasTower it's a guideline.